# ERROR: Plugin 'EmailComposer' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using Cordova 2.8.1 and am generated application using Terminal.

And i added **EmailComposer.h & EmailComposer.m** files in **Plugins**

and **EmailComposer.js** file in **www**.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="EmailComposer.js"></script>
```

added in **index.html.**

In plist file i added **key:** EmailComposer and **value:** EmailComposer in Plugins.

And finally in config.xml i added

```
<feature name="Plugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVPlugin"/>
</feature>
```

In button action am calling method

```
Cordova.exec(null, null, 'EmailComposer','showEmailComposer', ["emailID@gmail.com", "message"])
```

But am getting error as follows

```
ERROR: Plugin 'EmailComposer' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.

-[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 116] FAILED pluginJSON = [
"INVALID",
"EmailComposer",
"showEmailComposer",
[
  "emailID@gmail.com",
  "message"
]
]
```

Any suggestions for this problem
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in config.xml:

```
<feature name="EmailComposer">
      <param name="ios-package" value="EmailComposer"/>
</feature>
```

The first "EmailComposer" is the name of this plugin in JS side, and the second "EmailComposer" is the class name of this plugin in native(Objective-C) side .

Comment: Show me the crash messages!

Comment: BTW, did you get "EmailComposer" source code from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/EmailComposer ? According to it's "Read me":You need to add MessageUI.framework to your project if it is not already included

Comment: Ya, from there only am downloaded and am added  MessageUI.framework also.

Comment: In btn action -[EmailComposer appViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa881dc0
2013-07-10 15:22:18.598 ForwardAContact[6496:c07] ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[EmailComposer appViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa881dc0'
First throw call stack:
(0x16c012 0x29dfe7e 0x1f74bd 0x15bbbc 0x15b94e 0x3b23 0x62b24 0x6235c 0x61f1d 0x62086 0x61fc3 0x29f36b0 0x1618035 0xeff3f 0xef96f 0x112734 0x111f44 0x111e1b 0x38107e3 0x3810668 0x3a765c 0x2b4c 0x2aa5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: So plugin "EmailComposer" is found! Maybe you should debug this step by step :)