# Error in FIleUpload Plugin for iPhone

Tags: ios, cordova

I am getting below error after proper following instructions from here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/FileUploader

```
ERROR: Plugin 'FileUploader' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml. -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 116] FAILED pluginJSON = [ null, "FileUploader", "uploadByUri", [
```

Can anybody please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Which Phonegap version are you using..
Incase you are using any latest phonegap version you need to configure the plugin as a feature in config.xml and not as plugin.

Also try to get the latest updated patched code from GITHUB for this particular plugin.

Refer 
[ERROR: Plugin 'EmailComposer' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566440/error-plugin-emailcomposer-not-found-or-is-not-a-cdvplugin-check-your-plugi)